# HtmlAgilityPack UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c#, utf-8, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse my html doc, but I can't get the html correct.

For example:

```
string s="<!DOCTYPE html>
              <li>Voltage: <0.05% + 10 mV 
              (<0.1% + 25 mV for output 2 of E3646/47/48/49A)</li>
          </html>";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc;
doc.LoadHtml(s);
```

But I get:

```
"<li>Voltage: <0.05% +="" 10="" mv=""></0.05%><0.1% +="" 25="" mv="" for="" output="" 2="" of=""></0.1%></li>"
```

instead of:

```
"<li>Voltage: <0.05% + 10 mV (<0.1% + 25 mV for output 2 of E3646/47/48/49A)</li>"
```

What is the problem?

p.s. I have an another html doc with utf-8 encoding and it does not have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<` in the text of the `li`, causing `mV` etc... to be interpreted as attributes of the `0.05%` element (it is interpreted as an element, as there is a `<` preceding it).

You should escape these to `&lt;`.

```
string s="<!DOCTYPE html>
              <li>Voltage: &lt;0.05% + 10 mV 
              (&lt;0.1% + 25 mV for output 2 of E3646/47/48/49A)</li>
          </html>";
```

Comment: thank you, it is explain that the problem is not connected to the encoding, and this is an half answer. but: I cant change the text because I get it from the site. so do you have an another idea?

Comment: @Chanipoz - Not really. If you are not getting valid HTML, you need to tell the provider of the HTML that it is not valid and that they should fix it.

Comment: It's the only way? because I can't ask the the provider.

Comment: @Chanipoz - It is not valid HTML. If the provider claims it is, then they are wrong. Except for manually changing the values, I can't see a way to automate this.

Comment: see this page: http://www.ntecusa.com/product/dsp_unitDetails.cfm?productID=21336

Comment: @Chanipoz - I understand your frustration. I don't have much more to offer - try setting some of the different `OptionXXX` on the `HtmlDocument` before parsing - one of them might be of use.